# Plasmon and The Orientation of the Plasma Oscillation

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, plasma-physics, plasmon

The electric field wave resulting from plasma oscillation can be broken down into the transverse and longitudinal components, whose frequencies are given by

$$\omega_{transversal} = \sqrt{c^2k^2+\omega_p^2}$$
$$\omega_{longitudinal} = \omega_p$$

Here $\omega_p$ is the plasma frequency, $c$ is the speed of light, and $k$ is the wavevector of the electric field.

I was told that as quanta of plasma oscillations, plasmons correspond to the longitudinal component of the electric field wave. How is this so?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. That is the *definition* of a plasmon, so there is now "how". Can you clarify what your confusion is?

Comment: If that is so, then what is the reason that plasmon is defined as only the longitudinal oscillation? The plasma also oscillates transversally. Or is the answer is as simple as "Why not?". I can think of one reason, namely that the longitudinal oscillation is the "fundamental" one in the sense that the transversal oscillation modes are defined in terms of the oscillation modes by the fact that omega_tranversal contains omega_p.